# Remove ALL duplicates if columns are the same in MYSQL select query

Tags: mysql

I currently use the following to pull data  for today from my database:

```
select TheTime, Thename, theplace from Stats where Selection = "SIR" and Thedata > 19.99 and DATE(TheTime)  = CURDATE()
```

The field `TheTime` is a DateTime field. I would like to check if any duplicate times are in this field. If there are then remove them all from the select query.

I am only looking for results that have 1 distinct DateTime. I have tried to use `select DISTINCT TheTime` but it still pulled the non-distanct values.

Comment: What version your MySQL is?

Comment: 10.2.25-MariaDB-cll-lve

Comment: Those column names though.

Comment: `Selection = "SIR"` Make a habit out of it writing strings values in SQL with single quotes.. in the ANSI/ISO SQL standard double quotes means identifiers meaning columns and or table names..

Comment: @RaymondNijland thanks for the tip!

Comment: But also see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried the following query on my database:

```
SELECT DISTINCT createdOn FROM tbldata
```

The `createdOn` is `DATETIME` data element with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` default expression.
The query returns distinct values. My server version is 8.0.15, `InnoDB` engine

Be advised that

> In MariaDB, the DISTINCT clause doesn't ignore NULL values. So when using the DISTINCT clause in your SQL statement, your result set will include NULL as a distinct value.

https://www.techonthenet.com/mariadb/distinct.php

Comment: *"In MariaDB, the DISTINCT clause doesn't ignore NULL values. So when using the DISTINCT clause in your SQL statement, your result set will include NULL as a distinct value."* Wierd statement i think we found our new w3fools as it sounds like  `DISTINCT` in ANSI/ISO SQL standards is designed to ignore  `NULL` values..

Answer (score 0):

Try GROUP BY TheTime.

SELECT DISTINCT is working with keys so you would have to use TheTime as key to make it work.

Comment: GROUP BY TheTime will still give me 1 result depeding on order by would it not?